# Duplicate New User Registration notices (BuddyPress and bbPress both installed)

Tags: plugins, buddypress, bbpress

I am running WordPress 4.7.5.

I have bbPress and BuddyPress plug-ins installed (and others).

When a new user registers, I receive two identical email notices indicating New User Registration. Sent at the same time, same content, but with different message IDs.

What's more, in BuddyPress Activity feed, I show two identical activity items for "XXX became a registered member"

Has anyone else run into this and found the culprit, or a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with suggestion from here: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-hide-new-registered-member-update-from-activity-streams/

Adding this to functions.php removed one of the copies:

```
remove_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'bp_core_new_user_activity' );
```